# What's a cost-effective way to perform an Airdrop of erc-20 tokens

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, polygon

I want to reward addresses who bought into an ERC-20 token during a certain period. This would mean having a smart contract record each of the thousands of addresses, but smart contracts can't store a lot of data. also how do I also airdrop them in a cost-effective automated way

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to do it offchain.

Get the already deployed erc-20's address, get all the log emitted when a address bought, filter those logs for the period of time you want, then save the addresses you will airdrop tokens to.

Then you simply have to pass an array of addresses to your ERC-20 and do the airdrop.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not really during a certain time. it's when during a certain condition was in effect. I've read somewhere about saving the data using "mappings" but I'm not sure how that works. im trying to do this in a hand free automated kind of way.